# how many zookeper servers we need in order to support 18 kafka machines

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

6 kafka machines ( they are physical machines - DELL HW )

3 zookeeper server

we want to add 12 kafka machines to the cluster

in that case how many zookeeper server should be ?

in order to support 18 kafka machines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your question was tagged with Hadoop, but for Kafka alone, 3 will "work", but 5-7 is "better".

**But**, these should be **dedicated** Zookeeper servers for Kafka, and *not shared* with Hadoop services such as the namenode, Hive, HBase, etc. Especially on the level of 30+ Hadoop servers. This is because Zookeeper is very latency specific, and needs lots of memory to handle these types of processes.

This can easily be done in Ambari with specific server configs, but not letting Ambari use its templates to populate the single Zookeeper quorum that it tracks (which is somewhat painful to find in every service, that it's really worth not using Ambari at all for configs, and rather Puppet or Ansible, etc, but I digress)

Keep in mind, your cluster will be 1/3 entirely unbalanced, and adding brokers will not move existing data or cause replicas to get assigned to the new brokers for existing topics

Comment: dear cricket , you said 5 are better , but from reading in google I see that performance will be less then 3 zookeepers servers , can you approve this ?

Comment: you said - "This is because Zookeeper is very latency specific" and because that you prefer to install the zookeeper on separately HW without other hadoop services , I will with you honest , our zookeeper servers ( actually 3 ) are with hadoop services , but maybe we can solve it by other way for example increase the RAM memory / CPU , and installed the zookeeper with other hadoop services on physical HW instead on VM , what you think ?

Comment: Dedicated hardware will always be more performant than virtual, I've found. SSDs with Zookeeper can help as well, as mentioned in their documentation

Comment: good point to use ssd , even the zookper installed on VM machine , BTW , the SSD disk is the formal advice for zookeeper?

Comment: I think so. http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.12/zookeeperAdmin.html

Comment: Yes , I search in the doc bot not fins something that related to ssd , what we found is that zookper should not swap the disk or not use the swap , can you advice , where we can find the ssd for the zookeeper on document ?

Comment: since zookeeper very sensitive to swap , and the swap on zookepr server is 8G , is it good to decrease this swap to 0?

Comment: Swap off, and at 0, absolutely. Since you are just focused on Kafka w/ Zookeeper, you can find "Production deployment" whitepapers at Confluent's site. https://docs.confluent.io/current/zookeeper/deployment.html#disks